# I'm trying to create virtual enviroment for my project but below error is shown:

Tags: python

```
PS C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\> cd \~
PS C:\\Users\\HP\> cd documents
PS C:\\Users\\HP\\documents\> cd python
PS C:\\Users\\HP\\documents\\python\> py -3.11.1 -m venv pyAI
No suitable Python runtime found
Pass --list (-0) to see all detected environments on your machine
or set environment variable PYLAUNCHER_ALLOW_INSTALL to use winget
or open the Microsoft Store to the requested version.

PS C:\\Users\\HP\\documents\\python\>
```

Please help me to solve the problem i'm unable to create virtual enviroment

Comment: What does `py --list` say?

Answer (score 0):

Windows store version always presented some problems for me, try installing python using the installer and do not forget to set the path variable.
It usually also has problems creating virtual environments with capital case letters in its name, try all lowercase.